# Datatable fnRowCallback gaving error Jquery Datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working with datatable fnRowCallback is gaving error when aoData has 191 rows which are visible in the browser The thing it is doing is making background color change based on records as it is legacy system i cannot change the code much it is working in old project.

The problem occurs when have updated class library from packages.config to package reference
and Dev express version from 12.1 to 23.3

and it's also not coming in the controller.

My bundleconfig.cs file

```
     bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"
                        ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                        "~/Scripts/respond.js"));


            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datatableScript").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/moment.js",
                     "~/Scripts/DATATABLE/datatables.min.js",
                     "~/Scripts/pdfMake2/pdfmake.min.js",
                     "~/Scripts/pdfMake2/vfs_fonts.js",
                     "~/Scripts/datetime-moment.js"
                     ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dropdownSearchScript").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min_.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/jqueryStyle").Include(
                      "~/Content/jquery-ui.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css"));


            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/datatableStyle").Include(
                    "~/Content/DATATABLE/datatables.min.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/dropdownSearchStyle").Include(
                     "~/Content/chosen.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Select2Script").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/select2.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/Select2Style").Include(
                     "~/Content/select2.min.css"));
```

The order in which load scripts and css

```
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/jqueryStyle")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/datatableStyle")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/dropdownSearchStyle")
     @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")=
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatableScript")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dropdownSearchScript")

    <script src="~/Scripts/datetimepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/datetimepicker/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

[image: Error of controller]

```
                         
                    $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');
                    $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
   
                    $("#tblGrid").DataTable({
                       "order": [[0, 'desc']],
                        "lengthMenu": [[25, 33,50, 100, -1], [25,33, 50, 100, "All"]],
                        "pageLength": 33,
                        columnDefs: [
                            {
                                className: 'dt-center', targets: "_all", defaultContent: ""
                            }
                        ],
                        buttons: [{
                            extend: 'excelHtml5',
                            title: '',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: ':visible'
                            }
                        },
                            , {
                                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: ':visible'
                                }
                            }
                        responsive: false,

                        "dom": "<'row'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-4'B><'col-md-4'f>>" +
                            "<'row'<'col-md-12't>><'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",
                        colReorder: true,
                        fixedHeader: false,
                        keys: true,
                        select: true,
                        "orderCellsTop": true,
                        "bServerSide": true,
                        "sAjaxSource": "/Tickets/Home/LoadTxAsync",
                       "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                           debugger;
                            var activityID = $('#ddActivity').val();
                            var statusID = $('#ddStatus').val();
                            var TicketType = $('#ddtickettype').val();

                            let table = $('#tblGrid').DataTable();
                            let info = table.page.info().page + 1;
                            var Bank = $('#BankId').val();
                            var Start = $('#txtStart').val();
                            var End = $('#txtEnd').val();
                            debugger;

                            aoData.push({ "name": "activityID", "value": activityID },
                                { "name": "txtStatusID", "value": statusID },
                                { "name": "txtTicketType", "value": TicketType },
                                { "name": "currpage", "value": info },
                                { "name": "bankID", "value": Bank },
                                { "name": "Start", "value": Start },
                                { "name": "EndDate", "value": End },
                            );
                        },
                        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                            debugger;
                            console.log(aData[16]);
                            if (aData[10] == 'Closed') {
                                $(nRow).css('background-color', 'yellow');
                            }
```

[image: Error]

My Network tab

[image: Network tab which of JS are loaded]